# Mysql Connector error 1064 - Update with URL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I am working on a twitter app in python and I am trying to update a user record in my database. I can insert fine but updating presents the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064: You have an error in
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near '://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/
735726715267679398/m%HAWxt7_normal.jpg WHERE use' at line 1
```

Below is the code I am using for the UPDATE:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE user_table SET following='" + 
str(all_data['user']['following']) + "', followers_count=" + 
str(all_data['user']['followers_count']) + ", favourites_count=" + 
str(all_data['user']['favourites_count']) + ", friends_count=" + 
str(all_data['user']['friends_count']) + ", statuses_count=" + 
str(all_data['user']['statuses_count']) + ", verified=" + 
str(all_data['user']['verified']) + ", profile_image_url=" + 
all_data['user']['profile_image_url'] + " WHERE user_id=" + 
str(all_data['user']['id']))
```

I have then printed out the SQL to the screen below:

```
UPDATE user_table SET following='None', followers_count=252, 
favourites_count=3899, friends_count=12, statuses_count=506, 
verified=False, profile_image_url='http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images
/735726715267679398/m%HAWxt7_normal.jpg' WHERE user_id=2933205672
```

I have pasted this SQL into phpmyadmin and ran the SQL and it performed the update without any errors. 
Can anyone see a solution to this?

Comment: learn about prepared statements

Comment: How did you print the SQL query? I don't think, that they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523603/mysql-connector-error-1064-update-with-url#comment62539200_37523603) is right about the prepared statements. This is not only hard to debug, it's a security risk too. Your vunerable to SQL Injections.

Anyway, I think your problem here are the missing quotes.

```
...", profile_image_url='" + all_data['user']['profile_image_url'] + "' WHERE user_id="...
```

Comment: Yup it was just missing quotes, thanks for pointing that out. And i'll have a look into prepared statements